# SQL query to sort and select from the selected

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

i would some help with this issue , i have news tables 
i want to select 2000 terms and sort them, then check if the terms exist in the 2000 show it else 0. 
some thing like that .

```
 SELECT TOP 1000 [terms]
      ,[frequency]
      ,[occurance]
      ,[idf]
      ,[tfidf]
    FROM [Central].[news]
    ORDER BY tfidf DESC;

    IF @@ROWCOUNT= 0 

    select 0 as FinalResult;

    ELSE 
    if @@ROWCOUNT< 2000 
       select * from [CentralFinance].[dbo].[TFIDF_1]  where terms = 'project'
```

Comment: Your syntax is clearly SQL Server so I removed the extraneous database tags.

Comment: no idea what you want, You select 1000 rows then ask if `@@rowcount < 2000`. A litle more explanation is required

Comment: i want to select 1000 rows  ORDER BY tfidf DESC; then check if the term exist in the 1000 or not. if yes add 1 else 0

Comment: add `1 or 0` to to what? why order ? this is a great place to start  http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: let me explain to u, if u execute this query the answer will be 0 and it will select the term from all table. i want to select from top 1000   @@ROWCOUNT= 0 

    select 0 as FinalResult;

    ELSE 
    if @@ROWCOUNT< 1000 
       select * from [CentralFinance].[dbo].[TFIDF_1]  where terms = 'projects'

Comment: so what is the problem now?

Comment: it dosent select from the top 1000. i want to select 1000 order by DESC. then check if the term exist in this 1000 or not.

Comment: You have to put an effort in preparing the question. Show us some sample data, some desire result. this is a great place to start  http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/ and [**Need an Answer? Actually, No ... You Need a Question**](http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/jeffs/archive/2008/05/13/question-needed-not-answer.aspx)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps this is helpful. It is a total guess:

```
select top 2000 -- or 1000?
    terms, frequency, occurance, idf, tfidf
from Central.news
order by tfidf desc;

if @@rowcount > 0 begin
    select * from CentralFinance.dbo.TFIDF_1
    where terms in (
        select top 2000 terms
        from Central.news
        order by tfidf desc
    );
    select 1 as FinalResult;
end
else begin
    select 0 as FinalResult;
end
```

Another thought is:

```
if exists (select 1 from Central.news) begin
    select * from CentralFinance.dbo.TFIDF_1
    where terms in (
        select top 2000 terms
        from Central.news
        order by tfidf desc
    );
    select 1 as FinalResult;
end
else begin
    select 0 as FinalResult;
end
```

And finally a third guess:

```
select sgn(count(*)) as FinalResult
from (select 1) dummy
where 'project' in
(
    select top 2000 terms
    from Central.news
    order by tfidf desc
)
```

Comment: i have list of terms such (internet) how i can search for this term from 2000, if exist 1 else 0

Answer (score 0):

You can use a Temp table to store the initial query and the query the temp table for the new dataset. Or you can add a sub query to the where clause. What do you want returned from the query ?

Comment: thanks for ur replay, i want to return 1 or select the term if exist else 0